# Pandas aggregate batches to new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I've searched a lot, but maybe I'm too dumb to see the solution in other questions/answers.

I have stock tick data. Tick data looks like this:

```
    Bid     Ask     Price   Volume
0   12325.0 12335.0 12335.0 1
1   12330.5 12335.5 12335.5 1
2   12337.5 12340.0 12340.0 1
```

In code:

```
df_tick = pd.DataFrame({
    'Bid': [12325.0, 12330.5,12337.5],
    'Ask': [12335.0, 12335.5,12340.0],
    'Price': [12335.0, 12335.5, 12340.0],
    'Volume' : [1,1,1]
})
```

I'm trying to write an aggregator which aggregates n ticks into candle data. Candle data looks like this:

```
    Open Close  High    Low     Volume
0   NaN 12335.5 12335.5 12335.0 2.0
1   12330.5 12340.0 12340.0 12340.0 1.0
```

where

**Open**: Last price of the previous batch.

**Close**: Last price of current batch.

**High**: Maximum of the current batch.

**Low**: Minimum of the current batch.

**Volume**: Sum of all volumes of the current batch.

what I did is:

```
def aggregate_to_candles(data, step):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low'])
    
    for i in range(0, len(data), step):
        window = data.iloc[i: i + step]
        
        previous_close = data.iloc[i-1: i, 2].values[0]  if i > 0 else np.nan
        
        df = df.append({
            'Open' : previous_close,
            'Close': window.tail(1)['Price'].values[0],
            'High': window['Price'].max(), 
            'Low': window['Price'].min(), 
            'Volume': window['Volume'].sum()
            }, ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

Calling `aggregate_to_candles(df_tick, 2)` gives the aggregated result as shown above. Which seems to be correct.

Is this the way to do it? Is there a better/faster/easier way to do it? For my 5 million ticks aggregated into 150s batches takes pretty "long" time.
I tried to do it with rolling window, but I think the code is not worth to be shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Let us try `groupby` + `agg`

```
dct = {'Close': ('Price', 'last'), 'High': ('Price', 'max'),
       'Low': ('Price', 'min'), 'Volumne': ('Volume', 'sum')}

N = 2 # Aggregate on 2 second interval
candles = df_tick.groupby(df_tick.index // N).agg(**dct)
candles['Open'] = candles['Close'].shift() # last price of previous batch
```

---

```
>>> candles

     Close     High      Low  Volumne     Open
0  12335.5  12335.5  12335.0        2      NaN
1  12340.0  12340.0  12340.0        1  12335.5
```

Comment: I like your funny words, magic man :-) It's fast!! And the result looks correct! I try to understand what's going on. What is .agg(**dct) doing? Well, it calls the functions defined in the dictionary somehow. Do you know where can I find a reference for this?

Comment: @SvenBardos Glad i could help! `agg(**dct)` is use to aggregate the columns defined in the dictionary with their corresponding aggregation functions..For example `Price` column is aggregated using `max` and result is stored in newly created column `High` to get the maximum of current batch. For reference you can check [`this official guide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)